# Iterating over pattern

Tags: java

Suppose you're dealing with data organized in the following format:

```
[123]="some string" [234]=999999999 [345]="some other string"
```

In Java, what would be the easiest way to split each by KV combination, where K is the tag (enclosed in `[  ]`).

Is there a Utils (Apache or other?) method you know off that lets you define a structure as shown above to help with iterating over it, instead of having to manually count and read data past and between  `[  ]`?

What do we know?

- Each element will have a tag
- Each tag will be surrounded by `[ ]`
- Tag and value assigned to the tag will be separated by `=`
- Value will be there. No empty values allowed.
- Value may or may not be surrounded by quotes

Comment: Do you have control over the data format? If so, change it to something standard (say, JSON) and you'll be able to use existing libraries.

Comment: No. The only thing that is guaranteed is that data will be in `tag=value` format, where each tag will be enclosed by `[ ]` and value may or may not be surrounded by `"`.

Comment: If you don't want to write a parser by hand, you could use a [parser generator](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=parser+generator) that takes the grammar as an input and creates a parser (or parser+lexer) for you. I'm not sure that the juice would be worth the squeeze, though.

Comment: Do you get `[]="` in the values, maybe the Quotes masked by a backslash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `Pattern` with regex `"\\[(.*?)\\]=(.*?)( (?=\\[)|$)"` to grab pairs at a time.
The only limitation is that the next term is assumed to start at a space followed by a `[`, so this character sequence may not appear within a value.

This code demonstrates:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "[123]=\"some string\" [234]=999999999 [345]=\"some other string\"";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]=(.*?)( (?=\\[)|$)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String k = matcher.group(1);
        String v = matcher.group(2);
        System.out.println(k + "-->" + v);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
123-->"some string"
234-->999999999
345-->"some other string"
```

Comment: Very nice sir. Very nice indeed!

Comment: Updated code. It the string value contains `"` then it will be replaced with the blank string

Comment: @BhavikAmbani What are you talking about? If the value contains a double quote `"`, absolutely nothing strange will happen - these characters are not required in the input or defined in the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for [`java.util.Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `java.util.Properties` to read the data. After all, they're just `key=value` pairs.

For example:

```
String input="[123]=\"some string\" [234]=999999999 [345]=\"some other string\"";
input = input.replaceAll("\\s+\\[", System.getProperty("line.separator") + "[");

Reader in = new StringReader(input);
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(in);
in.close();
```

For extracting the data, use this:

```
private static String getValue(String key, Properties props) {
    return props.getProperty("[" + key + "]");
}
```

The results are as expected:

```
System.out.println(getValue("123", props));
> "some string"

System.out.println(getValue("234", props));
> 999999999

System.out.println(getValue("345", props));
> "some other string"
```

Comment: That is not the case. You get a stream of data which contains many pairs.

Comment: It might still be useful though. `Properties` loads its data from an `InputStream` or a `Reader`, by first replacing the spaces between records with line separators, it can correctly parse the values in your format. I'll work out an example.

Comment: @JAM I edited my answer with my proposed solution. It has the advantage of creating a map of values (the `props` object) for easily retrieving the values later on.

Comment: Also, very nice answer! Thank you Oscar!

Answer (score 0):

I'd use string.split(" ") to get all the key value pairs and then parse within each item using string.replaceFirst() twice (once to get the key and once to get the value).

I don't think this is the most efficient way, but it is easy with respect to typing.